# Grouping on any one of multiple columns in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, postgresql-9.5

Is it possible to create some sort of chain of grouping in Postgres? Let's say I have the following chart:

```
CREATE TABLE foo AS
SELECT row_number() OVER () AS id, *
FROM ( VALUES
  ( 'X', 'D', 'G', 'P' ),
  ( 'F', 'D', 'L', 'M' ),
  ( 'X', 'N', 'R', 'S' ),
  ( 'Y', 'I', 'W', NULL ),
  ( 'U', 'Z', 'E', NULL )
) AS f(a,b,c,d);

id | a | b | c | d
------------------
 1 | X | D | G | P
 2 | F | D | L | M
 3 | X | N | R | S
 4 | Y | I | W | 
 5 | U | Z | E |
```

I want to somehow craft a `GROUP BY` that yields three groups:

1. `1`, `2` and `3` together

   - `1` and `2` because of a common `D` in the `b` column
   - `1` and `3` because of a common `X` in the `a` column
2. `4` alone (no common values in any of the columns; nulls shouldn't match)
3. `5` alone (no common values in any of the columns; nulls shouldn't match)

I'm currently using Postgres 9.5, but we'll upgrade eventually to 9.6, so if there's anything in there that'll help me, I'm open to hearing it.

In other words, I'm looking for something like (let's say I used `array_agg(DISTINCT a)`, etc. to keep display simpler):

```
   ids    |     as     |     bs     |       cs        |      ds
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
{1, 2, 3} | {'X', 'F'} | {'D', 'N'} | {'G', 'L', 'R'} | {'P', 'M', 'S'}
{4}       | {'Y'}      | {'I'}      | {'W'}           | {NULL}
{5}       | {'U'}      | {'Z'}      | {'E'}           | {NULL}
```

(I'm not exactly sure how the nulls would display so don't get too hung up on that; the important point is that they shouldn't match each other.)

When I use `GROUP BY CUBE (a, b, c, d)`, I get way more than three results...ditto `GROUP BY ROLLUP` and `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS`.

Is there an elegant way in Postgres? I can imagine how you would do it in Ruby via Active Record (loop through every record, group it with previous grouped sets that match), but I'd like to keep this in Postgres if possible.

Answer (score 8):

Another recursive solution that:

- first creates the adjacency list of the connected graph of ids,
- then finds its transitive closure (this is the recursive part)
- and then groups by (once) to find the connected components that each node belongs to
- and joins to the table again and group by (again) to gather the values from all nodes of each connected component.

Initial data (copied from [Jack Douglas' solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/157717)):

```
begin;
create schema stack;
set search_path=stack;

create table foo as
select *
from (values (1,'X','D','G','P')
           , (2,'F','D','L','M')
           , (3,'X','N','R','S')
           , (4,'Y','I','W',null)
           , (5,'U','Z','E',null) ) AS f(id,a,b,c,d);
```

The query:

```
with recursive 
  al (tail, head) as                     -- adjacency list 
  ( select f.id, g.id 
    from foo as f join foo as g
      on (f.a = g.a or f.b = g.b or f.c = g.c or f.d = g.d) 
  ),
  tc (tail, head) as                     -- transitive closure
  ( select * from al
    union distinct
    select f.tail, g.head 
    from al as f join tc as g on f.head = g.tail
  ) ,
  cc (head, ids) as                      -- group once
  ( select head, array_agg(distinct tail order by tail) as ids
    from tc
    group by head
  ) 
select                                   -- group twice
    ids,
    array_agg(distinct a order by a) as a,
    array_agg(distinct b order by b) as b,
    array_agg(distinct c order by c) as c,
    array_agg(distinct d order by d) as d
from
  cc join foo on cc.head = foo.id
group by ids ;
```

```
┌─────────┬───────┬───────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│   ids   │   a   │   b   │    c    │    d    │
├─────────┼───────┼───────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ {1,2,3} │ {F,X} │ {D,N} │ {G,L,R} │ {M,P,S} │
│ {4}     │ {Y}   │ {I}   │ {W}     │ {NULL}  │
│ {5}     │ {U}   │ {Z}   │ {E}     │ {NULL}  │
└─────────┴───────┴───────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

Cleanup:

```
rollback;
```

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you are after a general solution, I don't think there is any non-recursive method of solving your problem. If your real-world problem needs to work with large numbers of rows you may have your work cut out getting a solution that scales well enough.

test schema and data:

```
begin;
create schema stack;
set search_path=stack;

create table foo as
select *
from (values (1,'X','D','G','P')
           , (2,'F','D','L','M')
           , (3,'X','N','R','S')
           , (4,'Y','I','W',null)
           , (5,'U','Z','E',null) ) AS f(id,a,b,c,d);
```

solution:

```
with recursive t(id,a,b,c,d,start,path,cycle) as (
  select *, id, array[id], false from foo
  union all
  select f.*, start, path||f.id, f.id=any(path)
  from foo f join t 
    on f.id<>t.id and
       (f.a=t.a or f.b=t.b or f.c=t.c or f.d=t.d) where not cycle )
select array_agg(f.id order by f.id) ids
     , array_agg(distinct a order by a) a
     , array_agg(distinct b order by b) b
     , array_agg(distinct c order by c) c
     , array_agg(distinct d order by d) d
from foo f join ( select start id, array_agg(id order by id) ids
                  from t
                  where not cycle group by start) z on z.id=f.id
group by ids::text;
```

```
┌─────────┬───────┬───────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│   ids   │   a   │   b   │    c    │    d    │
├─────────┼───────┼───────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ {1,2,3} │ {F,X} │ {D,N} │ {G,L,R} │ {M,P,S} │
│ {4}     │ {Y}   │ {I}   │ {W}     │ {NULL}  │
│ {5}     │ {U}   │ {Z}   │ {E}     │ {NULL}  │
└─────────┴───────┴───────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

cleanup:

```
rollback;
```