# Merge rows if any matches in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Given a table like:

| color | animal | place |
| --- | --- | --- |
| orange | bear | California |
| blue | bear | Tokyo |
| green | cat | Florida |
| purple | dog | Florida |
| purple | bird | Oklahoma |
| red | null | Oklahoma |

If *any* of the columns match, assume the rows should be combined

So,
the first two rows are combined because the animal "bear": matched.

rows 3,4,5,6 are combined because the country Florida matched and the color purple matched and the state Oklahoma matched.

the final output should be:

| colors | animals | places |
| --- | --- | --- |
| {orange,blue} | {bear} | {California,Tokyo} |
| {green,purple,red} | {cat,dog,bird} | {Florida,Oklahoma} |

(this is for entity resolution, they could have tons of ids in different systems and if any match I know that technically all match).

I have an idea for how to accomplish this by creating nested selects (or stacking views) and grouping by one column at a time but is there an easier way?

Comment: I would be surprised if there is an easy way to do this.

Comment: You say you know a way. Please show it to help us help you. Also your version of Postgres and, ideally, a fiddle to work with.

Comment: I edited to say I'm not so sure if I know how to do it... 
I started to do a group by on one column at a time then merge in values.
that group by is made harder by the fact that there are null values too so I had to union in after

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding my answer here:
[Grouping on any one of multiple columns in Postgres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/157715/grouping-on-any-one-of-multiple-columns-in-postgres)
the three steps I had to do in addition were:

- add an id to my table (which was actually a materialized view so didn't have one)
- add indexes for performance since it was large
- remove null values from the final array_aggregate